# I have a error in appscript with "e.value" and I do not know why

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

It's like I don't understand that "e" is an initializing event, the "newValue" and the "oldValue" are received from a dropdown in cell J32 in a sheet called "Format".
I have the following code, it is for a dropdown menu. I don't really understand with which line I activate the book, with which the current page (because there are several pages in the book) and neither does it because an error appears. I attach my code, thank you very much.

```
function onEdit(e){
  desplegableMultiRespuesta(e)
  }

function desplegableMultiRespuesta(e){  
  
  var celdaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange(); //Esta linea activa una celda
  var filaActiva = celdaActiva.getRow();
  var columnaActiva = celdaActiva.getColumn();
  var valorNuevo = e.value;
  var valorViejo = e.oldValue;

  var celdaResultado = celdaActiva.offset(0,1)
  var valorAcumulado = celdaResultado.getValue()
  
  if (columnaActiva==10 && filaActiva==32){
    if(!valorNuevo)valorAcumulado=""
    else if (!valorViejo) valorAcumulado=nuevoValor
    else if (valorNuevo!=valorViejo){
      valorAcumulado=valorAcumulado+", "+valorNuevo
    }
    celdaResultado.setValue(valorAcumulado)
  }
}
```

Please explain the problem to me with plasticine, I don't know anything about code. The error is

```
Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')
    at desplegableMultiRespuesta(desplegableMultiRespuesta:10:22)
    at onEdit(desplegableMultiRespuesta:2:3)
```

Comment: `nuevoValor` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote it like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" &&e.range.columnStart == 10 && e.range.rowStart == 32) {
    var v = e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue()
    if (!e.value) {
      v = "";
    } else if (!e.oldValue) {
      v = nuevoValor;//nuevoValor is undefined
    } else if (e.value != e.oldValue) {
      v = v + ", " + e.value
    }
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue(v)
  }
}
```

You were never getting the sheet and there is an undefined variable so I can't go much further.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')

It's like I don't understand that "e" is an initializing event, the "newValue" and the "oldValue" are received from a dropdown in cell J32 in a sheet called "Format"

Comment: You cannot run this function from the script editor it requires the event object from the triggger.  And creating it this way helps it to run faster and more reliably.

Comment: Thenxs, i dont know make this. You can plis help me tiping the code?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: Please give me the code to correct my error or the link to a video that explains in spanish the error.

Comment: This is an english only site and I don't know spanish.  You can try using an online interpreter.